# SQL Server : drop constraint if exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been struggling with this for about 2 hours now. I am trying to create a column to tables using a stored procedure. That said, I must check if that column exists, and if it does I must drop it.

The Issue is that I am not able to drop the constraint, I am getting an error:

> invalid column name 'RowNumber'

Code:

```
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @newColumnName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @newDefaultValue NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @newColumnType NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @constraintName NVARCHAR (30)

SET @tableName='TestTable'
SET @newDefaultValue = 'James'
SET @newColumnType ='NVARCHAR(100)'
SET @newColumnName = 'James'

CREATE TABLE #cons (constraintName NVARCHAR(100), RowNumber int)

INSERT INTO #cons(constraintName, RowNumber)
    SELECT 
        t.*
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             name, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS RowNumber 
         FROM 
             sys.objects 
         WHERE 
             type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT' 
             AND name like '%JAMES%'  
             AND name like '%JAMES%') AS t

    SELECT * FROM #cons

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
              WHERE TABLE_NAME = '[dbo].[TestTable]' 
                AND COLUMN_NAME = 'James') 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @i int
        DECLARE @numberOfRows int

        SET @i = 1
        SET @numberOfRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #cons)

        WHILE(@i <= @numberOfRows)
        BEGIN
            SET @constraintName = (SELECT constraintName 
                                   FROM #cons 
                                   WHERE RowNumber = @i)

            DECLARE @dropStatement NVARCHAR(500)
            SET @dropStatement = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @constraintName

            EXEC(@dropStatement)

            SET @i = @i + 1
        END                                     

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] 
        DROP COLUMN [James]
    END 

    --ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] ADD James NVARCHAR(50) 
    DROP TABLE #cons
```

How can I get this to drop the column?

Comment: that works. the issue is that i can not drop the constraint

Comment: I suggest you query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to see what the data in there looks like. `TABLE_NAME` will not be `[dbo].[TestTable]`.

Comment: What do you mean by *i cannot drop the constraint* are you getting any error ?

Comment: "so I am getting an error saying invalid column name 'RowNumber'"

Comment: what does the table name have to do with it?

Comment: @JamTay317 I don not see any possibility to get that error from your code . Are you sure this is the code that generated error message

Comment: yes tables hasn't been altered

Comment: Try running `DROP TABLE #cons` on its own in case you still have a copy of the temp table hanging around in your session with a different schema. Once you get past that though there are other issues with your script including the one raised by @ShannonSeverance

Comment: that was the issue.. thanks!

Answer (score -2):

ALTER TABLE 
DROP CONSTRAINT @constraintname

Before the drop colum

Comment: Oh, make sure you don't loop and remove the constraint multiple times.

Comment: ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT @constraintname this doesnt work Must declare the scalar variable "@constraintName". and i get Incorrect syntax near '@constraintName'.